# Term for a guarantee a manufacture makes that a product will be produced for a number of years?

Tags: terminology, manufacturing, production

Sometimes manufactures of electrical components guarantees that a product will be produced for a number of years so you can rely on getting new components for future production runs. What is the term for such a manufacture guarantee?

Sometimes this is something that you can buy, you can pay the manufacture up front for a guarantee that you will be able to buy the component X years from now. I know there is a specific term for this, but I cannot find it.

Comment: In quite a few instances the proper term would be "lie".

Comment: Sometimes this is something that you can buy, you can pay the manufacture up front for a guarantee that you will be able to buy the component X years from now. I know there is a specific term for this, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Active, Last Time Buy, Obsolete, Not for New Designs, Out of Business, pick any and always have a 2nd source

Comment: "Last Time Buy" is in the right neighborhood, but not exactly the term I am looking for.

Comment: One term used (NXP and the former Freescale) is Product Longevity. http://www.nxp.com/about/about-nxp/technology-leadership/product-longevity:PRDCT_LONGEVITY_HM

Comment: Lay aside = to save something for the future

Comment: @bjarkef You might want to put your first comment into the actual question. From what I understand, you want to tell the manufacturer something like _"I need a written contract that you guarantee the availability of this circuit until at least 2027. What will that cost me?"_ Every answer and comment so far seems to focus on what they already offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Longevity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longevity).

Examples:

- [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/about/about-nxp/technology-leadership/product-longevity:PRDCT_LONGEVITY_HM)
- [ST](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/support/resources/product-longevity.html)

It is especially important on digital components. You can exchange resistors and capacitors without problems, but digital parts require design and qualification.

Often a last-buy date is given. Before which you have to order your last batch. Keep an eye out for, or register to notifications of **Product Change Notes** (PCN). These will tell you when and how parts change. (eg: different plastics, different country of origin, new process)

Recently many semiconductor companies have merged and split. (atmel, nexperia, microchip, freescale) Often they will shuffle their assets, and those are production facilities. Expect PCN's after merges and splits.